# Problem with DataTable.Select

Tags: c#, datatable

Is there a way to find a value in DataTable use method Select:

`items.Select("Number like '%10%'");`

But Number type is Int, and this code doesn`t work...

Comment: you want to match any value that includes 10? so 12312310324235, 10 100, 234324510 would all match but 23432451 would not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the T-SQL [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) functions, they might help you here. Basically, in your query, use either `CAST` or `CONVERT` (not sure which is best suited for you) to change the int into a string that you can perform a `LIKE` on.

Comment: thanks, I just write new sql-query, where field 'Number' converts in varchar and then I put it in DataTable

Answer (score 1):

For those reading in the future, this might help:

```
DataRow[] matchingRows = a.Select("Convert(Age, 'System.String') like '2%'   "); // cut and paste from my code
```

So in your code it would be:

```
DataRow[] matchingRows = a.Select("Convert(Number, 'System.String') like '10%' "); // where Number is the name of your column.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have such behaviour, then it would be better just add to your table additional computed column like "NumberText" with type String, which will store the same values as for column Number. Then you can execute your expression: `items.Select("NumberText like '%10%'");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq the following way:

```
var matchingRows =
    from item in items.AsEnumerable()
    where item.Field<string>("Number").Contains("10")
    select item;
```

or if Number is actually a number:

```
var matchingRows =
    from item in items.AsEnumerable()
    where item.Field<double>("Number").ToString().Contains("10")
    select item;
```

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves you need to escape a single quote by doubling it. Ie:

```
items.Select("Number like ''%10%''");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataView to filter values in DataTable

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dtSample);
dv.RowFilter = "Number like '%10%'";
```